# join 2 sql queries that involve the same table i need to get the id back

Tags: mysql, sql

i have these 2 queries

```
select 
    count(1),
    female.first_name,
    female.last_name,
    male.first_name,
    male.last_name
from
    new_person as male
        left join
    new_person as female ON male.spouse_id = female.id
where
    male.spouse_id <> '0'
group by female.first_name , female.last_name , male.first_name , male.last_name;
```

and the second 1 looks like this

```
    select 
    male.first_name as fnf,
    male.last_name as lnf,
    female.first_name as fnm,
    female.last_name as lnm
from
    new_person as p1
        left join
    new_person as male ON p1.father_id = male.id
        left join
    new_person as female ON p1.mother_id = female.id
where
    p1.last_name <> ''
        and p1.last_name <> 'N.N.'
        and ((male.last_name <> ''
        and male.last_name <> 'N.N.')
        or (female.last_name <> ''
        and female.last_name <> 'N.N.'))
```

now i want to combine these to like 
where maleq1.name = maleq2.name and femaleq1.name = femaleq2
then sow me the id from the male and the female in both q1 and q2

with name i mean first_name and last_name

Comment: Im assuming your group by might make a difference. DiD you try to see if using temp table and finally calling the temp table would solve your requirement.

Comment: Your first query is an aggregate of your records.  In theory it could have many id's, right?

Comment: so what you suggest is make a table in with i put in the first and last name and the old id from both queries and then compair them?

Comment: Didn't look into example data but this sounds to me like an PIVOT query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:  Make a view out of each query.  Then write a 3rd query using your two views.

However, your first query is a aggregation/ rollup/ whatever of multiple records.  Add new fields to the query with the id's

```
CREATE VIEW q1 AS
select 
    count(1),
    female.first_name,
    female.last_name,
    male.first_name,
    male.last_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(male.id),
    GROUP_CONCAT(female.id)
from
    new_person as male
        left join
    new_person as female ON male.spouse_id = female.id
where
    male.spouse_id <> '0'
group by female.first_name , female.last_name , male.first_name , male.last_name;
```

Then your 2nd query

```
CREATE VIEW q2 AS
select 
    male.first_name as fnf,
    male.last_name as lnf,
    female.first_name as fnm,
    female.last_name as lnm,
    male.id AS male_id,
   female.id as female_id
from
    new_person as p1
        left join
    new_person as male ON p1.father_id = male.id
        left join
    new_person as female ON p1.mother_id = female.id
where
    p1.last_name <> ''
        and p1.last_name <> 'N.N.'
        and ((male.last_name <> ''
        and male.last_name <> 'N.N.')
        or (female.last_name <> ''
        and female.last_name <> 'N.N.'))
```

Use these for the third query